# Timer with intent extras

Tags: java, android, timer

So in `activity A` I want to have `SeekBar` which sets it's time on `TextView` below it.

That's done with this code:

```
  textViewDisplaySekundiVisokogIntenziteta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDisplaySekundiVisokogIntenziteta);


        seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta);
        seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta.setMax(60);
        seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta.setProgress(10);
        seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                textViewDisplaySekundiVisokogIntenziteta.setText(progress + " sekundi");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

But i don't have actual timer `TextView` in this activity (`TextView` that will decrease it's time every second), it's located in `Activity B`.

I'm trying to pass it in that activity like this:

```
  public void homeScreenStart(View view){
        new CountDownTimer(seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta.getProgress() * 1000, 1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Intent i = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, Timer.class);
                i.putExtra("visokiInterval", millisUntilFinished/1000);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.i("Finished", "Timer done");

            }
        }.start();
    }
```

NOTE - method `homeScreenStart` is called when `button` is pressed

And get it in `activity B` like this:

```
  textViewTimerVrijeme = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTimerVrijeme);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        if (b!=null){
            String j = (String) b.get("visokiInterval");
            textViewTimerVrijeme.setText(j);
        }
```

I don't get any logcat errors, but in `Activity B` I don't get that `TextView` visible, like it isn't there.

Where's the problem?

ACTIVITY B:

```
public class Timer extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView proba, textViewTimerVrijeme;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        textViewTimerVrijeme = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTimerVrijeme);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        if (b!=null){
            String j = (String) b.get("visokiInterval");
            textViewTimerVrijeme.setText(j);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_timer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_pause:
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: millisUntilFinished/1000 is string?

Comment: No, it's that long parameter from onTick method

Answer (score 0):

In putExtra  Pass string value

```
i.putExtra("visokiInterval", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000));
```

In activity b change

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String j = extras.getString("visokiInterval");
    }
```

Comment: No, that TextView is still not visible

Comment: It is up in first post

Comment: OK i managed to fix it but now when the timer is counting down on every second it looks like it's opening activity again and again